# "Invalid use of incomplete type" with forward declaration to avoid recursion by headers

Tags: types, declaration, forward

I have a class Fahrzeug (= Vehicle) and Weg (= Road). Weg has a vector storing all elements of Fahrzeug that are driving on it. Because both classes store stuff about the other class in this case, including "Fahrzeug.h" in "Weg.h" and vice versa would cause recursion to occur.
The way around this is to forward declare the other class in each classes header and only include the headers inside the .cpp files.

Sadly i get an error saying
*\main.cpp:253:15: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Weg'*
when creating an instance of Weg...

I traced the constructors with their initialization lists but cant find my mistake

```cpp
/*
 * Simulationsobjekt.h
 *
 *  Created on: 11.10.2022
 *      Author: nikid
 */

#ifndef SIMULATIONSOBJEKT_H_
#define SIMULATIONSOBJEKT_H_

#include <iostream>

class Simulationsobjekt
{
public:
    Simulationsobjekt(const std::string p_sName);
    virtual ~Simulationsobjekt();
    Simulationsobjekt(const Simulationsobjekt&) = delete;
    virtual void vSimulieren() = 0;
    virtual const void vAusgeben(std::ostream& ostream);
    virtual void operator=(const Simulationsobjekt& simulationsobjekt);
    virtual bool operator==(const Simulationsobjekt& imulationsobjekt);
protected:
    std::string p_sName = "";
    int p_iID = 0;
    static int p_iMaxID;    //noetig?
    double p_dGesamtZeit = 0.0;
};

//Operator muss global geschrieben werden, da er zu ostream und nicht Fahrzeug gehoert
//Es reicht aus es einmal fuer die Parent Klasse zu schreiben
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostream, Simulationsobjekt& simulationsobjekt);

#endif /* SIMULATIONSOBJEKT_H_ */
```

```cpp
/*
 * Simulationsobjekt.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 11.10.2022
 *      Author: nikid
 */

#include "Simulationsobjekt.h"
#include <iomanip>

#define IDWIDTH 7
#define NAMEWIDTH 15

int Simulationsobjekt::p_iMaxID = 0;

Simulationsobjekt::Simulationsobjekt(const std::string p_sName) : p_iID(p_iMaxID)
{
    this->p_sName = p_sName;
    p_iMaxID++;

    //Ausgabe
    std::cout << "Objekt (Name: " << p_sName << ", ID: " << p_iID << ") erzeugt" << std::endl;
}

Simulationsobjekt::~Simulationsobjekt()
{
    //Ausgabe
    std::cout << "Objekt (Name: " << p_sName << ", ID: " << p_iID << ") geloescht" << std::endl;
}

const void Simulationsobjekt::vAusgeben(std::ostream& ostream)
{
    ostream << std::setw(IDWIDTH) << p_iID
            << std::setw(NAMEWIDTH) << p_sName;
}

void Simulationsobjekt::operator=(const Simulationsobjekt& simulationsobjekt)
{
    p_sName = simulationsobjekt.p_sName;
    p_iID = p_iMaxID++;
}

bool Simulationsobjekt::operator==(const Simulationsobjekt& simulationsobjekt)
{
    return p_iID == simulationsobjekt.p_iID;
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostream, Simulationsobjekt& simulationsobjekt)
{
    simulationsobjekt.vAusgeben(ostream);
    return ostream;
}
```

```cpp
/*
 * Weg.h
 *
 *  Created on: 11.10.2022
 *      Author: nikid
 */

#ifndef WEG_H_
#define WEG_H_

#include "Simulationsobjekt.h"
#include "Tempolimit.h"
#include <list>
#include <memory> //noetig fuer unique pointer etc.

class Fahrzeug; //statt Header einbinden um circular dependecies zu vermeiden
class Weg : Simulationsobjekt
{
public:
    Weg();
    Weg(std::string p_sName, double p_dLaenge);
    Weg(std::string p_sName, double p_dLaenge, Tempolimit tempolimit);  //wie mache ich tempolimit optional???
    virtual ~Weg();
    double getTempolimit(Tempolimit p_eTempolimit);
    void vSimulieren() override;
    static const void vKopf();
    const void vAusgeben(std::ostream& ostream) override;
    //int getTempolimit(Tempolimit p_eTempolimit);
protected:
    const double p_dLaenge = 0.0;
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<Fahrzeug>> p_pFahrzeuge;  //Welche Art Liste?
    Tempolimit p_eTempolimit;
};

#endif /* WEG_H_ */
```

```cpp
/*
 * Weg.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 11.10.2022
 *      Author: nikid
 */

#include "Weg.h"
#include "Fahrzeug.h"
#include <iomanip>

#define LAENGEWIDTH 10
#define IDWIDTH 7
#define NAMEWIDTH 15
#define FAHRZEUGEWIDTH 20

Weg::Weg() : Simulationsobjekt(""), p_eTempolimit(Tempolimit::Autobahn) {}

Weg::Weg(std::string p_sName, double p_dLaenge) : Simulationsobjekt(p_sName), p_eTempolimit(Tempolimit::Autobahn), p_dLaenge(p_dLaenge)
{
}

Weg::Weg(std::string p_sName, double p_dLaenge, Tempolimit tempolimit) : Simulationsobjekt(p_sName), p_eTempolimit(tempolimit), p_dLaenge(p_dLaenge)
{
}

Weg::~Weg()
{

}

double Weg::getTempolimit(Tempolimit p_eTempolimit)
{
    return (double)p_eTempolimit;
}

void Weg::vSimulieren()
{
    /*
    for (auto& f : p_pFahrzeuge)
    {
        f->vSimulieren();   //simulieren aller Fahrzeuge.
    }
    */
}

const void Weg::vKopf()
{
    std::string separator = "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
        std::cout << std::left << std::setw(IDWIDTH) << "ID"
        << std::setw(NAMEWIDTH) << "Name"
        << std::setw(LAENGEWIDTH) << "Laenge"
        << std::setw(FAHRZEUGEWIDTH) << "Fahrzeuge"
        << std::endl;
}

const void Weg::vAusgeben(std::ostream& ostream)
{
    Simulationsobjekt::vAusgeben(ostream);
    ostream << std::setw(LAENGEWIDTH) << p_dLaenge;

    ostream << "(";
    for (auto& f : p_pFahrzeuge)
    {
        ostream << f->getName();
    }
    ostream << ")";
}
```

```cpp
/*
 * Fahrzeug.h
 *
 *  Created on: 01.10.2022
 *      Author: nikid
 */


#ifndef FAHRZEUG_H_
#define FAHRZEUG_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include "Simulationsobjekt.h"

class Weg;

class Fahrzeug : public Simulationsobjekt
{
public:
    Fahrzeug();
    Fahrzeug(const std::string p_sName);
    Fahrzeug(const std::string p_sName, const double p_dMaxGeschwindingkeit);
    Fahrzeug(const Fahrzeug&) = delete; //sinnvoll, da sonst eine Kopie (Duplikat) vorliegt, welche die selbe ID besitzt
    virtual ~Fahrzeug();
    virtual const void vAusgeben(std::ostream& ostream);
    static const void vKopf();
    virtual void vSimulieren();
    virtual double dTanken(const double dMenge = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity());
    virtual double dGeschwindigkeit();
    bool operator<(const Fahrzeug& fahrzeug);
    void operator=(const Fahrzeug& fahrzeug);

    //GETTER & SETTER
    const std::string getName();
protected:
    double p_dMaxGeschwindigkeit = 0.0; //const weg?
    double p_dGesamtStrecke = 0.0;
    double p_dZeit = 0.0;
};

#endif /* FAHRZEUG_H_ */
```

```cpp
/*
 * Fahrzeug.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 01.10.2022
 *      Author: nikid
 */

#include "Fahrzeug.h"
#include "Header.h"
#include "Weg.h"
#include <iomanip>  // std::setiosflags, std::resetiosflags

#define IDWIDTH 7
#define NAMEWIDTH 15
#define MAXVWIDTH 20
#define GESSTRECKEWIDTH 15

#define GESVERBRAUCHWIDTH 17
#define TANKINHALTWIDTH 12
#define VWIDTH 17



Fahrzeug::Fahrzeug() : Simulationsobjekt("")
{
    //p_iMaxID++; kein Counter, sondern bloss fuer ID-Vergabe gedacht
}

Fahrzeug::Fahrzeug(const std::string sName) : Simulationsobjekt(sName)
{
    //p_iMaxID++;
}

Fahrzeug::Fahrzeug(const std::string sName, const double dMaxGeschwindigkeit) :
        Simulationsobjekt(sName), p_dMaxGeschwindigkeit((dMaxGeschwindigkeit > 0) ? dMaxGeschwindigkeit : -1 * dMaxGeschwindigkeit)
{
    //p_iMaxID++;
}

Fahrzeug::~Fahrzeug()
{

}

const void Fahrzeug::vAusgeben(std::ostream& ostream)
{
    Simulationsobjekt::vAusgeben(ostream);
    ostream << std::setw(MAXVWIDTH) << p_dMaxGeschwindigkeit
            << std::setw(GESSTRECKEWIDTH) << p_dGesamtStrecke
            << std::setw(VWIDTH) << dGeschwindigkeit();
}

const void Fahrzeug::vKopf()
{
    std::string separator = "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(IDWIDTH) << "ID"
    << std::setw(NAMEWIDTH) << "Name"
    << std::setw(MAXVWIDTH) << "MaxGeschwindigkeit"
    << std::setw(GESSTRECKEWIDTH) << "Gesamtstrecke"
    << std::setw(VWIDTH) << "Geschwindigkeit"
    << std::setw(TANKINHALTWIDTH) << "Tankinhalt"
    << std::setw(GESVERBRAUCHWIDTH) << "Gesamtverbrauch"
    << std::endl;


    std::cout << separator;
}

void Fahrzeug::vSimulieren()
{
     double dZeitDifferenz = dGlobaleZeit - p_dZeit;    //Gesamtzeit um vergangene zeit erhoehen
     if(dZeitDifferenz == 0) return;
     if(dGeschwindigkeit() > 0)
     {
         p_dGesamtZeit += dZeitDifferenz;
     }
     p_dZeit = dGlobaleZeit;
     p_dGesamtStrecke += dGeschwindigkeit() * dZeitDifferenz;   //Strecke = v * dt
}

double Fahrzeug::dTanken(double dMenge)
{
    return 0.0;
}

double Fahrzeug::dGeschwindigkeit()
{
    return p_dMaxGeschwindigkeit;
}

bool Fahrzeug::operator<(const Fahrzeug& fahrzeug)
{
    return p_dGesamtStrecke < fahrzeug.p_dGesamtStrecke;
}

void Fahrzeug::operator=(const Fahrzeug& fahrzeug)
{
    p_sName = fahrzeug.p_sName;
    p_dMaxGeschwindigkeit = fahrzeug.p_dMaxGeschwindigkeit;
    p_iID = p_iMaxID++;
}

const std::string Fahrzeug::getName()
{
    return p_sName;
}
```

```cpp
/*
 * Tempolimit.h
 *
 *  Created on: 12.10.2022
 *      Author: nikid
 */

#ifndef TEMPOLIMIT_H_
#define TEMPOLIMIT_H_
#include <limits>

enum class Tempolimit
{
    Innerorts = 50,
    Landstrasse = 100,
    Autobahn = std::numeric_limits<int>::max() // unbegrenzt/unendlich
};

#endif /* TEMPOLIMIT_H_ */
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Forgot to include Weg.h in main.cpp... 6 hours for THIS